# Laravel update multiple rows using checkboxes

Tags: laravel, checkbox, eloquent

I need to understand how to use the laravel eloquent way to update multiple rows in a database, based on which checkboxes have been checked. I am using the following code right now, which is working to a certain extent:

```
public function save()
{
    $post_data = Input::get('checkbox');

        if(is_array($post_data))
        {
            foreach ($post_data as $checkbox)
            {
                    $product        = Products::find($is_checked);

                if(!empty($checkbox))
                {
                    $product->is_checked    = '1';
                }
                else {
                    $product->is_checked    = '0';
                }
                    $product->save();
            }
        }

    Session::flash('success', 'Success message here');
    return Redirect::to('overview');
}
```

It does save the "is_checked" values, when a checkbox is selected. In the database it sets the value to "1". But if I uncheck a checkbox, it does not update the row and the "is_checked" stays at "1".

But that is not my main concern. What I wish to do, is not to use a foreach for this, because I need to update multiple rows each time, usually I need to update 100+ rows, so running 100 seperate queries is not the way to go.

**First question:**
How do I update multiple rows in my mysql table by checking or unchecking checkboxes using the laravel eloquent model?

**Second question**
How do I update other fields with different values based on which checkbox has been selected and based on the dropdown that comes with it? Example below:

```
<form name="bla">

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{ $id from database }}>
<select name="number">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
And so on..
</select>

</form>
```

I have multiple checkboxes with a select menu behind it. What I wish to accomplish is the following:

[x] Checkbox with ID 1 - Select menu option selected = 1

[x] Checkbox with ID 2 - Select menu option selected = 5

[x] Checkbox with ID 3 - Select menu option selected = 10

When I select three checkboxes, all 3 corresponding rows should be updated in the database. So in the above example, the following should happen:

Database row with id 1 should get a "1" value for "is_checked" and the "number" field should be "1"
Database row with id 2 should get a "1" value for "is_checked" and the "number" field should be "5"
Database row with id 3 should get a "1" value for "is_checked" and the "number" field should be "10"

I hope this explanation makes it clear as to what I want to accomplish and I hope it is not confusing in any sort of way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with unchecking boxes and records not updating is that if a checkbox is unchecked it doesn't get submitted as a value.

One way to garner which have been unchecked is compare the original data set with the checkboxes submitted, compare them to the stored values and update them if they differ

To handle updating lots at once you need to select and update at once by preparing your query in advance and then updating.

As you're checking and unchecking this will likely still require two queries.

Loop through all of the ID's to create a results set for those being checked and those unchecked

the `findMany` method works well for selecting a bunch

You can then do the entire process with a single line..

`Products::findMany($checkedIDs)->update(['is_checked' => 1]);`

`Products::findMany($unCheckedIDs)->update(['is_checked' => 0]);`

If you're trying to update different values on different records you will still need to do individual queries I believe SQL doesn't support a UPDATE X = Y WHERE ID = 1 AND UPDATE X = Z WHERE ID = 2...

it's always `DO UPDATE values TABLE WHERE clause`, in any situation that has varying `values` or `clause` you need separation.

Comment: Also `Products::find` will still accept an array and do the correct call under the hood

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, this is something for me to play with. Maybe I can simply reset all checked values in the database to 0 and then simply update the database using the submitted form. That will work. The findMany should do what I want as well. Thanks!